# My dog has ME and sits in a Bailey chair. Occasionally he ends up sitting on his tail. He now has a spot on it that has hair missing. What is it?

Tags: grooming

My dog sits in a Bailey chair for feeding. Occasionally he ends up sitting on his tail. It now has an area on it that has no hair. He does not lick or chew on it. What is this and how do I treat it?

Comment: Is the bald area in a spot that frequently contacts with the ground or the chair? Sometimes dogs and cats lose hair just from rubbing it off. Does the exposed skin look healthy? Any redness or anything?

Answer (score 2):

It's normal for all but the smallest dogs to get bald spots in the areas they often lay on. For most dogs that are spots on their legs and the breast bone. The reason is that these spots touch the ground when lying down and the hair is simply rubbed away by repeated contact with the ground.

The skin on these spots often becomes rough and thick, like a callus.

As long as the skin isn't injured, red or bruised I see no reason to worry.